# How to add languages for OCR recognition in Windows powertoys?

Tags: windows, powershell, powertoys

Hello I am trying to figure out the text extractor function in powertoys. From the internet tutorials, I have installed multiple languages for OCR from Windows powershell and restarted powertoys. However, it still cannot recognize the language (except English) I circled. How to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: Have you validated that the OCR recognition supports the target language?

Comment: Provide the output of the following command which requires elevation: `Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like 'Language.OCR*' }` as an [edit] to your question

Comment: Though I cannot speak to Windows OCR, the best OCR application I've used is free Tesseract, https://github.com/tesseract-ocr, which supported 126 languages when I last checked: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files-in-different-versions.html . For a Windows GUI, try FreeOCR, http://www.paperfile.net/ . The GUI appears to be unchanged since 2015, but still works well. To install more languages in FreOCR, see http://www.paperfile.net/lang.html

Comment: You can also try [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/), it's free. To use OCR, you should go to "Hotkey settings" and add OCR, then head over to "Task settings" > "OCR" and enable "Process OCR silently" and "Automatically copy results to clipboard".

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should zoom in on the image before performing OCR on it because it increases the chance of the characters being properly recognized.